# NestJS / CrudController Swagger as GetManyBase

Tags: swagger, nestjs

how do I decorate a custom method inside my CrudController so that the Swagger documentation would be shown as the one from getManyBase? Meaning I need to have all of the filter fields.

I tried this way

```
 @Get('/projects')
  @UseInterceptors(CrudRequestInterceptor)
  @ApiResponse({ status: 200, type: Project, isArray: true })
  getManyProjects(@ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest, @Request() request)
    : Promise<GetManyDefaultResponse<Project> | Project[]> {
    const { id, role } = request.user;
    if (role === UserRoles.User) {
      req.parsed.filter.push({
        field: 'userId',
        operator: 'eq',
        value: id,
      });
    }
    return this.projectService.getMany(req);
  }
```

but the Swagger docs shows empty for the query parameters, 
[image]

while I'm expecting something like `getManyBase`.
[image]

Funny thing is, the method would work properly if I send the `filter` string, but I need Swagger to display them as well. 
Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this area in the [nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/blob/607d47e0491c5289d109cfcd2800ba58c4c409c4/packages/crud/src/crud/crud-routes.factory.ts#L393) repo.

If you add something like this to your constructor that should do it:

```
import { Swagger } from '@nestjsx/crud/lib/crud';

...

constructor() {
    const metadata = Swagger.getParams(this.getManyProjects);
    const queryParamsMeta = Swagger.createQueryParamsMeta('getManyBase');
    Swagger.setParams([...metadata, ...queryParamsMeta], this.getManyProjects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my version "@nestjsx/crud": "^5.0.0-alpha.3"

```
import { Swagger } from '@nestjsx/crud/lib/crud';

...

constructor() {
    const metadata = Swagger.getParams(this.getManyProjects);
    const queryParamsMeta = Swagger.createQueryParamsMeta('getManyBase',{
      model: { type: MyModel },
      query: {
        softDelete: false,
      },
    });
    Swagger.setParams([...metadata, ...queryParamsMeta], this.getManyProjects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor approach does not work for you. Then probably your controller has [scope: REQUEST](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#injection-scopes). So controller instance is not created while application initialisation. In this case, you can have custom method inside a controller, like

```js
initSwagger() {
  const metadata = Swagger.getParams(this.getManyProjects);
  const queryParamsMeta = Swagger.createQueryParamsMeta('getManyBase',{
    model: { type: MyModel },
    query: {
      softDelete: false,
    },
  });
  Swagger.setParams([...metadata, ...queryParamsMeta], this.getManyProjects);
}
```

then in your main entrypoint file you can write:

```js
app.get(YourController).initSwagger();
```

It will do the trick